# Как получить данные от локации пользователя в Telegram боте + python в виде в котором отправляет пользователь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, геолокация

Это часть кода

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start (message):
    #Клавиатура с кнопкой запроса локации
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Поделись местоположением", reply_markup=keyboard)

 #Получаю локацию
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['location'])
def location (message):
    if message.location is not None:
        print(message.location)
        bot.send_message(admin_id, message.location)
        # print(message)
```

В котором пользователи отправляют свое местоположение, вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я хотел бы получать в Telegram боте локацию пользователей точно в таком же формате, Но получаю ее в формате долготы и широты, возможно ли получить в формате в котором отправляют пользователи, вместо того чтоб получать только координаты?

P.S А получаю я так

В терминале
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В админке (Где нужно получить, но в формате который у пользователей)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Она в таком виде и отправляется. Карта показывает клиент телеги и на разных устройствах она выглядит по разному

Comment: @AlexeyTen то есть я не смогу получить ее виде карты, вместо координат? Я просто тестировал это с одного устройства, но с разных аккаунтов

Comment: Воспользуйтесь например Яндекс картами. Там вроде есть вам которое выдаёт картинку по координатам  Ну  или какой-либо другой сервис